# Best way to write a class that I can re-use to represent the CurrentUser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my components I will need to reference the current user of my reactjs application.

I will store some of the information in localStorage (if it is safe too).

What I want is that in my components I can do something like:

```
var currentUser = GetCurrentUser();
currentUser.sessionToken 
currentUser.firstName
currentUser.timezone
currentUser.email
currentUser.logout()
```

My currentUser will also depend on using the localStorage API to get the sessionToken etc.

What would be the best way to write this class?  Also, for testing purposes, should the localStorage be a construct parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Use A HOC.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const withAuthentication = (Component) => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        authUser: null,
      };
}

getChildContext() {
     return {
       authUser: this.state.authUser,
     };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   Call function to get signed-in user (authUser => {
      authUser
        ? this.setState(() => ({ authUser }))
        : this.setState(() => ({ authUser: null }));
  });
}
   render() {
     return (
       <Component {...this.props}/>
     );
   }
}
WithAuthentication.childContextTypes = {
  authUser: PropTypes.object,
};

 return WithAuthentication;
}

export default withAuthentication;
```

Then wrap your Parent component in it

Parent

```
Parent.contextTypes = {
  authUser: PropTypes.object,
};
```

`export default withAuthentication(Parent)`

Now reference `this.context.authUser` anywhere in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many, many ways. In previous projects, I have set/read `currentUser` in `App.js` from `componentWillMount` (leveraging localStorage), and then passed down `currentUser` as a prop. In retrospect, using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) would have saved me some grief — this way you're not passing down `currentUser` to components which may not need it.

Something like this (not tested):

```
const UserContext = React.createContext()

class UserProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { 
      currentUser: null
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
     // Check localStorage for token
     // If present: GetCurrentUser() from backend and 
     // then this.setUser provided everything looks dandy
  }

  setUser = currentUser => {
    this.setState({ currentUser })
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props

    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{
        currentUser: this.state.currentUser
      }}>
        {children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

const UserReliantComponent = () => (
  <UserContext.Consumer>
    {({ currentUser }) => (
      {/* Use currentUser at will */}
    )}
  </UserContext.Consumer>
)

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <UserProvider>
        <A>
          <B>
            <C>
              <UserReliantComponent />
            </C>
          </B>
        </A>
      </UserProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

You could combine this with a Higher-Level Component in order to further abstract some of the logic.